# What is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 -1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

What is $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 -1}$$
There is a generalized formula for $\frac{1}{n^2+a^2}$. But why about negative $a$?

Comment: For $n=1$, $n^2 - 1=0$.

Comment: Oh sorry $n=2$, thanks for that

Comment: I think it should be,  $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 -1}$

Comment: $n^2-1 = (n+1)(n-1)$ so you should think about whether $\frac{1}{n^2-1}$ can be written as $\frac{A}{n+1}+\frac{B}{n-1}$ for some real values of $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{n^2 -1} = \frac{1/2}{n-1} - \frac{1/2}{n+1}$$